# Selecting an object via scripting?

Tags: python, scripting, selection-tools

As shown below, I have 2 nested spheres, each with a different material (inner = "1", outer = "2"). Ultimately, I need to select the inner sphere (material "1") via python scripting.

I've found a number of ways to select (or make active) one of the spheres. However, even though Blender says that it's selecting the correct sphere (indicated by orange line around center sphere), I don't believe it's active -- adding a modifier applies it to the outer sphere instead. That, and the material properties show the properties of the outer sphere.

[image: different materials]

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
bpy.data.objects['Sphere.017']
```

refers to an object. (Lets assume all names in quotes are the names of objects in your Blender Scene)

2.8 Recent Version of the API

```
bpy.data.objects["Cube"].select_set(True)
# to select the object in the 3D viewport,

current_state = bpy.data.objects["Cube"].select_get()
# retrieving the current state

# this way you can also select multiple objects

bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects['Sphere']
# to set the active object
```

[image]

https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.LayerObjects.html#bpy.types.LayerObjects

---

⚠Older Version of API 2.79

A python script can do something with that.

You can also use

```
bpy.data.objects['Cube'].select = True
# to select the object in the 3D viewport,
# this way you can also select multiple objects

# additionally you can use
bpy.context.scene.objects.active = bpy.data.objects['Sphere.017']
# to make it the active selected object
```

Comment: Atomic -- this was precisely was looking for (last suggestion). I don't know how I missed this in the online literature. Thank you!!!

Comment: For some inexplicable reason, in Blender 2.8 you have to use `obj.select_set(True)` with a different method for checking selection: `obj.select_get()`

Comment: This answer no longer works for Blender 2.8. I've tried it and there are no such fields in object like select, or active.

Comment: But it works another way - here is the solution: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132825/python-selecting-object-by-name-in-2-8

Comment: Correct version on how to set the active object: `bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.context.scene.objects['Cube']` (in 2020), see: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/132829/31447

Comment: "Please don't edit someone elses question to reflect edits to your answer." Thanks. From the revisions of the question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/38618/revisions Notice that a moderator already rolled back your ediits as well.

Comment: Is there any other easier ways of doing that, like copy python reference from the outliner, or having it displayed in the "info" pannel so it's easier to copy it afterward ? Like for example if I select from the outliner, I have "bpy.ops.outliner.item_activate(deselect_all=True)" it would be better to have full text.

Answer (score 21):

I'm just doing my duty here. Quick answer that works in 2.8:

```
objectToSelect = bpy.data.objects["objectName"]
objectToSelect.select_set(True)    
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = objectToSelect
```

You need that last line. Without it I couldn't switch into edit mode. I got the answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/124628/82018). I wanted to post it [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/124624/select-an-object-with-python-in-2-8/124626#124626), which is actually the question that comes up when you google this, but it has been locked and now only points to this question which thanks to @piotao pointed me to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You say that the modifier doesn't get added to the right object - the selected and active objects are only an issue if you are using operators, by directly manipulating data you don't have to bother with what is selected or active unless you want to know the selected object/s as the items that the script will work on.

The line -

```
mod = bpy.data.objects['Cube'].modifiers.new(name='subsurf',type='SUBSURF')
```

will add a subsurf modifier to the object named 'Cube' and return the modifier item to the mod variable. You can then use `mod.levels = 3` to set the viewport subdivisions and `mod.render_levels = 3` to set the render subdivisions.

For the type value of a modifier you can find [a list here](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_4/bpy.types.Modifier.html#bpy.types.Modifier.type).

Comment: **NOTE: this does not work in 2.8**
If you find this article and are working on 2.8 or newer the syntax is now: ob = bpy.context.scene.objects["Cube.031"] bpy.objects is NO MORE....

Comment: @NoirTalon `bpy.data.objects` still exists in 2.80. Using the 2.80 release I see that this works but there is a delay in updating, the viewport and properties don't show the result until you do something else (like zoom the viewport or click on the object), this is no longer the case with the daily build so will be fixed in 2.81.