# Creating primitive changes selection

Tags: add-on, selection-tools

I am writing a blender addon that shows a panel with an enum property in the object properties. In some cases if the user changes the enum value, the addon needs to create a new object. I managed to get this working using the update callback of the enum property and `bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()`. Unfortunately, this changes the object selection so that the right column of the blender UI suddenly displays the properties of the new object. Is it possible that the original object stays selected and that the UI keeps displaying my addon panel with the properties of the original object?

I tried to restore the original selection by calling `bpy.ops.object.select_all(action="DESELECT")` followed by `obj.select = True`. This does select the original object, but the right column of the blender UI still displays the properties of the new object.

I think I need a python command that performs the same action as clicking an object in the scene graph panel, but I could not find any in the blender documentation.

Answer (score 0):

From https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38626/58482 I found out that I need to set the `active` object in addition to selecting it. So using `bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj` after creating the new object seems to solve the problem.