# Python path for allowing animation of viewport and render visibility of objects

Tags: python, animation, scripting, objects, visibility

EDIT: It turns out I formulated this question out of a misunderstanding of my own old code. See @batFINGER and @scurest answers.

I'm working on a script which automates some animation, which includes turning on and off objects' viewport and render visibility with Object.hide_viewport and Object.hide_render. These objects will be created with the script.

In the Object Properties tab under 'Visibility', there is a button besides the 'Show in Viewports' and 'Show in Renders' buttons that allows these settings to show up in the Dope Sheet and be animated. I've attached a photo of these buttons, highlighted in red. How can I access these 'Animate property.' buttons with Python? As in what value do they change? Nothing shows up when hovering over this button with Python Tooltips on, nor does anything show up in the scripting info view when I click this button. Or is there an alternate way to do this?

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: If you are creating an object in Python please indicate so and show a small Python script sample.  Thus at creation time you would have the variable reference for the newly created object.  Object creation is really a separate question.  This comment was motivated by a comment below which can be moved to the original question.

Comment: I know how to create objects. I'm asking if there is a Python pathway for the Animate property buttons in the Object Properties -> Visibility tab.

Comment: Was the newly created was linked into the scene?  Can you show your sample?  If you are just changing a value then the Blender UI should update without your assistance.  If you feel you must reach the UI  button I will let some other reader assist you.  I tend to change values and curves points not UI buttons.

Comment: If your question is about [keyframe] CRUD create, read, update, delete please add that to your original question.

Comment: What do you mean? I'm programming a script that creates and animates a large amount of objects automatically. I want to program them to appear and disappear with the script. I know how to do this without a script, and I know how to script animation, but I cannot find a way to access the 'Animate property.' button above with Python so I can program visibility to be animated via script.

Comment: Many people have done what you are doing, including myself.  I think I will let one of them work with you.  I do not think we understand each other or maybe we need the privacy of our own minds to think about the problem. Final Suggestions .. think of Keyframes.  If keyframes do not work  there are Post and Pre Python Handlers which execute in sync to a frame change.

Comment: Please search frame_change_post and frame_change_pre

Comment: Yes, I think we are misunderstanding each other. Basically, If I knew the value that this button changed, I could do what I want to do. I think I have everything else figured out. I'm a self taught programmer, so forgive me if my language is imprecise or if I'm missing something..

Comment: The data_path you need to use for an fcurve is 'hide_viewport' and 'hide_render' if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are called [decorators](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/controls/buttons/decorators.html)

> Clicking on the decorator dot icon will add a Keyframe to that property. Clicking the rhombus icon again will remove the keyframe. A solid rhombus icon indicates there is a keyframe on the current frame, while a non-solid rhombus icon indicates that the property has a keyframe on another frame. Clicking the non-solid rhombus icon will add a keyframe to the current property value and frame.

They reflect the state of the assigned action, so instead of "using them" from Python, you can just change the action. For example

```py
import bpy
ob = bpy.context.active_object
assert ob.animation_data is None  #assume it's not animated yet
ob.animation_data_create()
ac = bpy.data.actions.new('Visibility Action')
ob.animation_data.action = ac
fc = ac.fcurves.new(data_path='hide_viewport')
fc.keyframe_points.add(2)
fc.keyframe_points.foreach_set('co', [0,0,10,1])  #frame 0 = show, frame 10 = hide
```

Comment: This answers my question, thanks! I've been going about it a totally different way, making adjustments to an object's properties, then inserting a keyframe for that property with my_ob.keyframe_insert(data_path="name_of_property_path", frame=num_of_frame).

Comment: I noticed with this method, If I add more than 2 keyframe points, I have to add the line fc.update() to make it function predictably. If not, looking in the graph editor, the tangents/"Bézier handles" of the keyframe points will all extend to [0, 0], warping the shape of the curves.

Answer (score 3):

**Keyframe Insert / Delete.**

*Further to the answer of @scurest*

[image]
*Mouse over the property after setting to refresh the panel*

Every object in blender has a [`keyframe_insert`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.bpy_struct.html#bpy.types.bpy_struct.keyframe_insert) and `keyframe_delete` method.   It does everything required, *eg* if the object has no animation data or action it adds them, then adds the keyframe.

Set the value, insert the keyframe. *eg* hide the object at frame 10

```
>>> C.object.hide_viewport = True
>>> C.object.keyframe_insert('hide_viewport', frame=10)
True
```

Can pass the frame, or it defaults to the current frame of the scene.

Comment: This is actually the method I was using before asking this question. However, keyframe_insert was not working to animate the visibility of objects unless - what I now know is called a decorator - was clicked. At least in Blender 2.9 for Mac OS X, I couldn't find the python path to 'press' the decorator/activate the animateability of visibility properties through script.

Comment: No issue on _Ubuntu_  The edit added hides the object at frame 10.

Comment: Well I realized my mistake and keyframe_insert is in fact working now... It was a dumb mistake.

Comment: single keyframe? once off always off?

Comment: I thought my keyframe_insert method was inserting a keyframe for any changed data paths rather than just one specific data path. So I didn't make a keyframe_insert for hide_viewport/hide_render specifically... I put them in my code a while ago for other data paths but kind of forgot how it worked, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

This indicates whether or not a keyframe exists for this property, and is also a toggle to create or delete a keyframe on the current frame in the timeline.

'Animate property' is maybe not the most helpful tooltip.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Please Try

```
bpy.context.object.hide_viewport = True
bpy.context.object.hide_render = False

#Python Console 
>>> bpy.context.object
bpy.data.objects['Text.023']

bpy.data.objects['Text.023'].hide_viewport
True

>>> bpy.data.objects['Text.023'].hide_viewport = False
```

Of course in the script you would refer to a particular object or sequence of objects by name or as part of a collection

Strongly related.
[Selecting an object via scripting?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38618/selecting-an-object-via-scripting/38626#38626)

Comment: I know how to turn on and off the visibility of an object with scripting, but apparently this cannot be keyframed by default. All with a script, I need to create an object, then allow the visibility to be keyframed with the 'Animate property.' button shown in the image, and then the visibility settings can be recorded on the timeline. But I can't find a path to activate the Visibility -> Viewports/Renders -> 'Animate property.' button via script.

Comment: You seemed to have changed the question.  If you move your comment to your original question others can more easily see it.   I will comment on your original question.

Comment: I edited for (hopefully) clarity, but the question is the same. But I can add my comment here to my main question too.